# Failed to run custom build command for `time v0.1.25`

Tags: rust

I am trying to compile a script using `cargo build --release` but get the following output ([full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/PTGanvK4)):

```
running: "gcc" "-O0" "-c" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-mwin32" "-m64" "-fPIC" "C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\time-0.1.25\src/time_helpers.c" "-o" "D:\Projects\hots-unpack\target\release\build\time-e758cbe877e9589d\out\src\time_helpers.o"     

failed to run custom build command for `time v0.1.25`

Process didn't exit successfully: `D:\Projects\hots-unpack\target\release\build\time-e758cbe877e9589d\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)

--- stderr
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\gcc-0.3.4\src\lib.rs:380
```

This is the [script](https://github.com/athre0z/hots-unpack) I want to compile

Comment: The build is trying to run `gcc`. Do you have GCC installed?

Comment: Yes, and added to the path-var.

Comment: Just to double check, what happens if you run `gcc --version`?

Comment: I get `gcc (GCC) 4.8.1`

Comment: Hm, that seems fine... could you try running the command yourself to get the full picture, i.e. `"gcc" "-O0" "-c" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-mwin32" "-m64" "-fPIC" "C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\time-0.1.25\src/time_helpers.c" "-o" "D:\Projects\hots-unpack\target\release\build\time-e758cbe877e9589d\out\src\time_helpers.o"` (the library used to run gcc doesn't print the compiler's output when it fails, [#36](https://github.com/alexcrichton/gcc-rs/issues/36)).

Comment: I get `C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\time-0.1.25\src/time_helpers.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in`. So it has something to do with my architecture? Sorry, really new in rust and gcc.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gcc on windows, but that suggests you may have a 32-bit version, while a 64-bit one is needed. I'm unsure of details, but maybe the [instructions for building rust itself from source on windows](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/#building-on-windows) might make progress (you'll want the x86_64 toolchain).

Comment: Yeah, I'm betting that you need the 64-bit version of GCC. Building rust-crypto doesn't even work on a 32-bit Windows 7 VM, complaining about usage of the `xmm1` and `xmm3` registers.

Comment: Many thanks to you, 64 bit version of gcc fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the 64bit version of gcc for windows: http://mingw-w64.org

Working like a charm now.